# published Android App Is Not Visible On Google Play

Tags: android, publishing, google-play

I just published my first android application on Google Play. However, although i see the app on developer console as published, i can't see it on Google Play.

I tried to access it from direct url via package name but it didn't worked also. Direct link is just below:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.serdar.sozluk

Can anyone know what problem is?

Comment: its there, plz check again. You can check again.

Comment: it take 10-30 minutes and some times about 1 hour.

Comment: it 'll take a bit time ......just wait .......

Comment: is this some thing like "Learning English Words"

Comment: see this i found your application https://play.google.com/store/search?q=%C4%B0ngilizce+Kelime+&c=apps

Comment: is this same what you are looking for ? Now it is visible there......... ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yiAN1.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a language related issue. Your application name is not in English that's why you are not able to find your aoolication

Your application does not display in list because may be you are searching for

**"Learning English Words"**

just try to search this word [this](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Learning%20English%20Words&c=apps)

**İngilizce Kelime Öğreniyorum** [this](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=%C4%B0ngilizce%20Kelime%20%C3%96%C4%9Freniyorum&c=apps)